# Emulating Messaging and Linked Inbox UI

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm creating my first Windows Phone 8 application and I have decided to write a simple ToDo application. I want to emulate the native UI experience as much as possible. In this case I've chosen the `Linked Inbox` and `Messaging` apps to emulate.

I've got the main look and feel easy enough by using the `Pivot` control and the `ListBox` control. What I can't figure out how to do is to emulate the behavior of tapping the left edge of the screen to put the list into a multiselect mode where check boxes will appear next to each item.

I've looked at both the `ListBox` and the `LongListSelector` controls. The latter only appears to support selecting a single item, so it looks like I need to use the `List` control.

I'm wondering if there is a 3rd control I haven't found yet that does what I want, or if the functionality I'm looking for isn't baked into a control by default and I essentially need to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Corrected `List` to `ListBox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this functionality from the MultiSelectList from the Windows Phone Toolkit which is published by Microsoft on NuGet. 
For examples of how to use it see http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-MultiselectList-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API. Or else see the sample project from the source code on Codeplex

Comment: Can this toolkit be used with Windows Phone 8? It looks like it's designed for WP7.

Comment: Sure: there's a version for WP8 as well.

Comment: I searched around and found a link to the WP8 toolkit: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/20/windows-phone-toolkit-overview.aspx. It looks like it has exactly what I need, thanks!